# List most common item sharing a group in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count, inner-join, aggregate-functions

Having a table with group ids and items like this:

```
group   item
-------------
1         A       
1         B
1         C    
1         D     

2         D     
2         A   
2         B   

3         B 
3         C 
3         D

4         A 
4         D 
4         E 

5         A 
5         D
```

How can I retrieve the most common item found together with a specified item? In the above table, the most common item for **A** would be **D**.

Comment: what does `select version();` say?  if there's a tie, what do you want?

Comment: @ysth it's MySQL 5.6

Comment: are items really single characters?  what is the column definition?

Comment: it's a varchar(255)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about ties then `group by item` and get the 1st item with the most occurrences:

```
select item
from tablename
where item <> 'A' and `group` in (select `group` from tablename where item = 'A')
group by item
order by count(*) desc limit 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=011772c937dbfd20ef2d36b1a1be4f8a).
Results:

```
> | item |
> | :--- |
> | D    |
```

Comment: Nice concept. :)

Comment: oh, I totally missed the "with a specified item" part of the question; given that, this is the right approach (or the equivalent join variant)

Answer (score 4):

You can self-join, aggregate and filter:

```
select item, item2 most_frequent_item, cnt
from (
    select t1.item item, t2.item item2, count(*) cnt, 
        rank() over(partition by t1.item order by count(*) desc) rn
    from mytable t1
    inner join mytable t2 on t1.grp = t2.grp and t1.item <> t2.item
    group by t1.item, t2.item
) t
where rn = 1
```

This works in MySQL 8.0 only (where window functions are available), and allows ties, if any (if you don't want ties, use `row_number()` instead of `rank()`).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8751f1091341e7a285b10b9c5519d715)**:

```
item | most_frequent_item | cnt
:--- | :----------------- | --:
A    | D                  |   4
B    | D                  |   3
C    | B                  |   2
C    | D                  |   2
D    | A                  |   4
E    | A                  |   1
E    | D                  |   1
```

---

In earlier versions, this is a bit more complicated. One option uses a `having` clause:

```
select t1.item item, t2.item most_frequent_item, count(*) cnt
from mytable t1
inner join mytable t2 on t1.grp = t2.grp and t1.item <> t2.item
group by t1.item, t2.item
having count(*) = (
    select count(*) cnt
    from mytable t11
    inner join mytable t21 on t11.grp = t21.grp and t11.item <> t21.item
    where t11.item = t1.item
    group by t11.item, t21.item
    order by count(*) desc limit 1
)
order by t1.item
```

Comment: maybe explain the choice between rank and row_number

Comment: you want `!=`, not `<`

Comment: Thank you, but I need it to run in MySQL 5.6

Answer (score 1):

Favoring the highest in case of a tie:

```
select item,substring(max(related_items),11) most_common
from (
    select t1.item,concat(lpad(count(*),10,'0'),t2.item) related_items
    from t t1
    join t t2 on t1.grp=t2.grp and t1.item != t2.item
    group by t1.item,t2.item
) related_items
group by item
```

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=47ad17e48d8a24128e4ca00d81b9813a